# Как правильно вернуть массив из функции на Pure C?

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели

Можно ли в C сделать тип возвращаемого значения `int* func(void)` или правильнее возвращать массив через ссылку в аргументах функции `void func(int *mass)`?

```
int* f()
{
    int a[2] = {4, 5};
    int* p = a;
    p = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    p[0] = a[0];
    p[1] = a[1];
    return p;
}


void f(int* p)
{
    int a[2] = {4, 5};
    p[0] = a[0];
    p[1] = a[1];
    //use function malloc in main
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Если размер массива известен заранее, то безопаснее создать его в вызывающем коде (второй вариант), т.к. и выделение и освобождение памяти будет производится одним программистом.
- Если размер не известен, то необходимо его возвращать на ряду с указателем на массив (иначе массив бесполезен), либо делать дополнительный метод возврата необходимого размера массива (как в WinAPI, например возвращается размер, если передать NULL, если передать указатель на массив, то он заполняется + для безопасности передаётся размер созданного извне массива).

> ```
> int f(int *pArray, int nMax)
> {
>   if (!pArray)
>       return 2; //запрос размера
>   if (nMax < 2)
>       return 0; //ошибка (не достаточно места)
>
>   int a[2] = {4,5};
>   pArray[0] = a[0];
>   pArray[1] = a[1];
>   return 2; //возвращаем размер
> }
> ```

Comment: Спасибо) то что искал)